# "00" in =iferror(time()) checking not work

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to check if a cell value is the same format as time,

but i don't want to use time type this time.

So I used the formula of

```
=IFERROR(TIME(MID(N4,1,2),MID(N4,4,2),0),"false")
```

It is the result of cell N4:

- 00:00 -> false(expected to be true)
- 01:00 -> true

How to read the 00:00 correctly?

Comment: TEXT function??

Answer (score 1):

You can confirm if a cell is in a time format by using the formula called [cell](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf). In your example, if you wish to check if the format in cell `A1` is time format, you could use this to return `true` or `false`.

`=OR(CELL("format",A1)={"D6","D7","D8","D9"})`

The value is likely already a time and by trying to strip out the displayed values won't work (similar to if you tried to strip out a `$` from a cell in currency format).

Answer (score 0):

Excel has probably automatically set the cell format for your values
as time, not as text.
In my test, when I entered the value `00:00` Excel has immediately
defined the cell type as Custom with the format of "hh:mm".

You may convert the type of the cells to Text by selecting the range/column,
right-click and select "Format Cells...".

Or you may modify your formula to be :

```
=IFERROR(TIME(MID(TEXT(A1,"hh:mm"),1,2),MID(TEXT(A1,"hh:mm"),4,2),0),"false")
```

Or you may create a new cell and use it instead of A1
in the formula as :

```
= TEXT(A1,"hh:mm")
```

Answer (score 0):

I read your question as having a value in N4 that is specifically not formatted to display as time. Further, while that reading does not preclude it being a numerical value, the more likely thing would seem to be it is a text string that you want to test for matching how it would look if it WERE a time and Excel were displaying it appropriately, matching what is shown in your question.

So, I believe you have "00:00" and "01:00" as text strings. And your desire is to check that the text strings match the logical time format that Excel writes as "hh:mm" AND that you want a "true/false" output.

If so, there are some problems and potential problems in your situation. It is very doable, but not necessarily as presently set up.

First, as mentioned by both other answers, it is possible that Excel has actually changed your data to truly be not just a number, but a true time value (decimal in the range of 0 to 1). For example, if hand entered into a cell not already formatted as Text, Excel would convert when "Enter" is pressed. If imported, either from a file or a direct paste into the spreadsheet, there's a very high chance it was converted and a very low chance that you happened to do it in a way that did not convert.

What happens then? Well, it IS then in a number format... and is a number. Don't think that's what you were shooting at, but perhaps it is acceptable. If it is an "OK" thing, you can set up an `IF` that first tests for a number using `ISNUMBER` and if so, you can test the appearance/format of it using `CELL` as `pgSystemTester` brought up. Do that as the TRUE branch of the `IF(ISNUMBER(` test. Write it to test the format returned for a "D" as the first character. "D9`is, I believe, the code for the "hh:mm" but I could be wrong. If the precise time format is important, enter a value, format it for the "hh:mm" format and see wwhat`CELL("format",` returns.

If not a number, then you have text, assuming no errors are present. And you can use the FALSE branch of the `IF` to look into that.

So... how? Well, if it is text, as I believe you intend it to be, you can use the following, or something similar, in your FALSE branch as the test:

```
TEXT(VALUE(N7),"hh:mm")=N7
```

This takes the string in N4 and converts it to a number. If it can. "00:00" becomes "0" for real in the `VALUE` function. "Horse" generates an error. If you indeed have a string that can be made into a number, then it formats it for the "hh:mm" format but keeps it as a text string and compares it to the (expected to be) text string already in N4. Note that if N4 has a time-appearing string in it, but of a different format, there will be a mismatch, so it is checking for that specific format being there, not for any and all formats for times. At this point, you are mostly there, so to speak.

Your `IF` had a true branch that happens if there was a numerical value in the cell and a false branch that happens if there is a string in the cell. The false branch makes the check for whether the string is formed the way the "hh:mm" format would present a time value. But... if you had an entry of "horse" that branch will fail. You could continue a couple ways depending upon your needs:  one would be to "wrap" that part in an `IFERROR` so that "horse" gives a chosen value rather than generating an error, and one would be to have further formula to evaluate the "doesn't match that time format" result.

Second, there are some very basic problems with your whole approach. First one is that a string of "00:00" is evaluated by Excel in its working through your formula as "0"... not as "00:00" and that happens regardless of whether it is an actual string, or if it has been converted to a number by Excel. That means the `MID` functions are not going to do what you are looking for. Why not? Well, the second one looks at character 4 and takes it and one more character to present as the minutes parameter for `TIME`. Except there isn't a 4th character. There is just the sole "0" character. That means that parameter becomes `""` and the function fails generating an error. Other values for the string do work, but only because no other string equals exactly 0. For instance the text string "01:00" is evaluated to 0.04166... (1/24th of the span from 0 to 1) and then `MID` finds the 4th character to be "4" and takes the "1" along with it as you specified two characters starting at the 4th one. This means the parameters you present to `TIME` are "0" hours, "41" minutes, "0" seconds and they give a decimal between 0 and 1 of 0.028472... which is not an error, like "00:00" gives.

So the general approach in the formula you give just cannot work if the inputs are text strings. That kind of indicates maybe they ARE numbers but... the question doesn't make a lot of sense if so. The only thing I see squaring that circle is you thought of or found on a help site this basic approach, but did not realize that it can't be applied to text strings. It cannot do what I think you're describing though.

Second is that the formula, as shown, will generate a real time value, not a true or false. And definitely not a `TRUE/FALSE` (the former being text strings and the latter being a true Boolean value Excel recognizes as such). There must be more to your formula because as shown it will NEVER give a result of "true" (or `TRUE` for that matter) as you show in the question.

Third, the described situation demonstrates why you do not want to add `IFERROR` into your formulas until you know precisely how they will work with all the possible  kinds of input and how each stage of the formula works. Putting them in too early can mask what is happening from your sight. Us them, to be sure, but hold off on putting them in until everything works.

A basic description of the formula workings above for evaluating a real string is that Excel will convert the pieces to numbers anyway, so you force that to happen on your own terms, and immediately convert back to a number as Excel is trying to do. That means you gain a test "for free" that tells you if the string has something other than numerical characters and the ":" and lets you control precisely the text output of that part of the formula so you can be sure the output is in the desired format. Then it compares that resulting string to the existing string in N4. Controlling the process to this point rather than letting Excel make its best guesses of what to do means you have exactly the comparison you want. If this bit is placed in an `IF` test, it can branch for good vs. not good and let you handle each as desired. It can also allow for a "real" `TRUE/FALSE` output.